# Lua code does not send an email

Tags: email, lua, smtp, debian, sendmail

I am using below code to actually send the email. But I do not receive any error and also no email.

```
    -- requires an SMTP server to send emails

    local smtp = require("socket.smtp")
    local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
    local mime = require("mime")

    from = "<sender@dataday.com>"

    rcpt = {
      "<aqs@dataday.com>"
    }

    -- the multipart message definition
    mesgt = {
      headers = {
        to = "<aqs@dataday.com>",
        subject = "Sending attachment over e-mail test"
      },
      body = {
        -- the message content
        [1] = {
            body = "Sending you a nice file! :D"
        },
        -- the file attachment
        [2] = {
            headers = {
                        ["content-type"] = 'attachment; name="test.txt"',
                        ["content-disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="test.txt"',
                        ["content-description"] = 'test binary file',
                        ["content-transfer-encoding"] = "BASE64"
            },
            body = ltn12.source.chain(
                    ltn12.source.file( io.open( "/opt/test.txt", "rb")),
                    ltn12.filter.chain(
                            mime.encode("base64"),
                            mime.wrap()
                    )
            )
         }
      }
    }

    -- send the message
    r, e = smtp.send{
      from = from,
      rcpt = rcpt,
      source = smtp.message(mesgt),
      user = 'sender@dataday.com',
      password = 'XXXXXXX',
      server = "smtp.1and1.com",
      port = 587,
      use_ssl = 'try'

    }
    print(r,e)
```

The above code gives me below output.

```
1       nil
```

Don't know which parameter i am setting wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you check on your spam box. Do it works without attachment? Automatic mail tend to go there. In any case I recommend to send the mail with sendmail (as API, and ev.with some nullmailer). So you have queues and logs.

Comment: Yes, I have checked my spam box. Nothing was there too. But I did not check email without attachment. I have another python script which successfully sends the mail with attachment. Thanks for you rely. I will try with sendmail.